# Oracle Apex How to access the role of user(:APP_USER) in SQL of page

Tags: oracle, authorization, oracle-apex, restriction

I have a page like this:

[image]

I want to add a restriction for link "Client Info"(last Column) based on the role of user, for example if user1 has the role of 'ACC' then just can see the "Client Info" who registered in 'ACC' service. Each person has the column called service which can registered in different services such as 'ACC'.

I have access to the :APP_USER in the sql of this page but I don't know how to apply a restriction base on the role of user?

Please help,
Thanks Mali

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to "map" each user to their roles. One option is to create a separate table with two columns: `app_user` and `role`. Add that table into your query (into the `FROM` clause) and check whether that particular user has role you're interested in.

Alternatively, create a stored function which accepts `app_user` and `role` and returns 1 (if user is granted that role) or 0 (if it is not). Why wouldn't you return Boolean? Because you can't use such a function in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I've just need to know if I can do that with APEX_APPL_ACL_ROLES and apex_appl_acl_users?

Comment: I wouldn't know.